# Bluetooth driver Failed and unable to install bluetooth driver for jammy ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, realtek

```
ravilinux@ravilinux:~$ sudo systemctl restart bluetooth 
ravilinux@ravilinux:~$ sudo dmesg | grep Bluetooth


[    3.239939] usb 1-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[    4.956735] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.956788] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.956796] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.956802] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.956813] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.338745] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
[    5.341199] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    5.341208] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852bu_fw.bin
[    5.342405] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852bu_config.bin
[    5.342664] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 38955
[    5.546321] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.546330] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.546338] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.730752] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0xdfb791cb
[    5.866763] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)
[    5.881766] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP extensions version v0.96
[    5.881772] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP quality report is not supported
[    5.881901] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[    7.943469] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    7.943483] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    7.943491] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    8.080736] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)
[    8.095750] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP extensions version v0.96
[    8.095755] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP quality report is not supported
[   54.038088] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x041a length: 7 > 1
[ 2882.309453] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)
[ 2882.324794] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP extensions version v0.96
[ 2882.324802] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP quality report is not supported
[ 2882.828425] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)
[ 2882.843407] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP extensions version v0.96
[ 2882.843416] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP quality report is not supported
[ 3156.099898] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)
[ 3156.114921] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP extensions version v0.96
[ 3156.114929] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP quality report is not supported
[ 3920.682045] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)
[ 3920.697076] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP extensions version v0.96
[ 3920.697085] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP quality report is not supported
[ 3920.682045] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read codec capabilities (-22)
```

Due to this I'm unable to get my bluetooth paired to my wireless devices.

I tried:

```
sudo apt search realtek bluetooth
sudo apt search bluetooth 
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
sudo apt search firmware-realtek-rtl8723cs-bt
sudo apt search firmware-realtek-rtl8723de-bt
sudo apt search firmware-realtek-rtl8723DE-bt
sudo hcitool -a.
sudo apt install bluez bluez-firmware
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
sudo dmesg | grep Bluetooth
```

Now I need to connect my bluetooth with wireless devices. What should I do? I'm also unable to install bluetooth driver for my 22.04.4 LTS ubuntu and its Realtek.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [ubuntu.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).